# following emberjs guide for #linkTo helper does not display individual post

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxWzu/2/)** with a route as shown below, which is exactly thesame as the one in **[emberjs guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/)** and when I click on the **#linkTo helper** attached to **{{post.title}}**, it ought to show me the individual post but it does not and instead the console shows this errors:

**Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.**

Also when I click the posts link on the home page, it displays all the titles but in the console, it also shows this error:

**Uncaught Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.**

```
EmBlog.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", function(){
    this.route('show', {path: '/:post_id'}) ;
  });
});
```

The template which is thesame as the [emberjs guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/index">
  {{#each post in content}}
    <p>{{#linkTo 'posts.show' post}} {{post.title}}  {{/linkTo}}</p>
 {{/each}}
</script>
```

I looked at this **[commit that added support for string literals as param for {{linkTo}}](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/b2e82aecf22c2654eb6e6894f5a0b82e2adfe5ed)** and in particular the suggestions  below from that commit:

Now, Ember allows you to specify string literals as arguments. **{{#linkTo post popular}}** would look up the "popular" property on the current context and generate a URL pointing to the model with that ID. While **{#linkTo post "popular"}}** would treat the string literal "popular" as the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the only issue was you forget to pass the context to the linkTo posts.edit helper in the posts/show template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/show">
  <h1>Post</h1>
  <p>Your content here.</p>
  <h3> {{title}} </h3>
  <h3> {{body}} </h3>
  <br/>
  <p> {{#linkTo 'posts.index'}} back {{/linkTo}}</p>
  <p> {{#linkTo 'posts.edit' content}} Edit the post  {{/linkTo}}</p>  
</script>
```

Here is a working fiddle, BTW I've cleaned up a bit, some things seemed useless for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/rxWzu/9/

Comment: Thanks @sly7_7 for the answer. Enjoy your day.

Comment: You're welcome :), BTW is almost finished here ^^ the evening starts...under the snow ;)

Comment: nop, in the linkTo helper, the first argument must be a route name (as define in the router). see http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/